# DateTime error when updating rows using EF

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, entity-framework-4, datetime2

I have a method that gets an existing row from a table in my database and updates some values on it and then save those changes.  The table in quesiton has these columns:

[image: columns in table]

The code that does the updating is here:

```
        public void Update(Accommodation accommodation, string code, int supplierId)
        {
            var existingAccommodation = Get(a => a.Code == code && a.SupplierId == supplierId);

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            existingAccommodation.ModifiedDate = now;
            existingAccommodation.Description = accommodation.Description;
            existingAccommodation.Introduction = accommodation.Introduction;
            existingAccommodation.Name = accommodation.Name;
            existingAccommodation.Strapline = accommodation.Strapline;
            existingAccommodation.Type = accommodation.Type;
            existingAccommodation.Processed = true;

            DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The problem is that the line `DataContext.SaveChanges();` causes an exception whose innerexception says:

```
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

This is where the above code is called

```
            Accommodation existingAccommodation = GetByCode(code, supplierId);
            if (existingAccommodation != null)
            {
                _accommodationRepository.Update(
                    accommodation, code, existingAccommodation.SupplierId);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `Update` method and the argument `accommodation` gets created. This error usually means that you have DateTime.Min value in of the entity fields. Maybe you save multiple entities in your method...

Comment: done - please take a look.  Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It is only 1 entity I save and the two dates modfieddate and createddate are populated.

Comment: I see no `CreationDate` being set, though. Is it sql-server 2005 maybe?

Comment: I figured out the problem.  The problem was that I had another Accommodation object that I "newed" just before calling the Update method and it was that object that EF was trying to save as well.